# Strategy Games Online Resources

Tags: game-design

I am looking for some good online (ebooks) resources about strategy games discussing the gameplay and the interactive aspects of strategy games, and how to design interesting and challenging strategy game.

I found this book (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Game-Guru-Strategy-Dave-Morris/dp/1904705456) and seems interesting by reading table of contents. Unfortunately, I did not find any way to buy an ebook version of it and I am in Middle East and ordering this book would take lots of time.

Any idea?

Comment: Ordering a book from Amazon shouldn't take more than 15 minutes (my wife and I have bought books through Amazon before and it's usually only taken ~5 minutes of our time to do so).  Is Amazon's book ordering process very different for people in the Middle East?

Comment: @Randolf, not sure if you're being sarcastic for any reason ot not, but I'm pretty positive OP is talking about the shipping time rather than just the ordering itsself. Dont forget english is not the first language for everybody in the world

Comment: @Maik Semder:  No, I wasn't being sarcastic -- in some countries the governments place a lot of requirements on popular web sites to operate in a certain manner (e.g., to comply with local laws) or face being blocked entirely (such as what happened to Google in China in recent years).  I've also found that shipping times vary from days to weeks, or even months, and I believe this is mostly dependent on the seller and the method of delivery, but that's for physical books; the questioner also mentioned ordering an "eBook."

Comment: @Randolf: I meant shipping time, although I think ordering books from amazon.com would imply both buying the book and shipping it.
I am trying to find an ebook about the subject as I don't want to wait weeks for shipping the book from USA. Thx!

Comment: @Ahmad, there are also amazon branches in Europe that might be faster for you, not sure though

Comment: Amazon says its 30 days tops for middle east http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=596204

Comment: @Maik: Amazon may say what they want, but the customs of every country may prolong these times indefinitely

Comment: Right @Lo'oris, good point. In that case, check my answer, it has the contact information of the publisher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't read it already try The Art of Game Design by Jesse Schell. It's available for Kindle and very good, but not specific to strategy.

I publish books and ebooks for game developers so if you have a clear idea of what you want please post the idea here: http://www.google.com/moderator/#16/e=7d41d

Answer (score 2):

You can try to contact the publisher, and ask them directly. [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=rVX3EJWw3BYC&source=gbs_book_other_versions_r&cad=3) states the publisher is "Thomson Course Technology".

[This page](http://officialcorp.com/thomson-course-technology-5470/) says they were renamed to "Cengage Learning", it also has all contact information, so you can just call or send an email to ask them directly for their ebook offers.